# sql function for the most recent value in a grouping

Tags: database, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks a bit like this:

```
create table Stuff
(StuffID int identity not null,
 StuffPrice decimal (8,2) not null,
 StuffPriceTime datetime not null)
```

I'm grouping by minute, so I can see the prices. My query looks like this:

```
Select functionNeeded(StuffPrice),
CAST(datepart(month,StuffPriceTime ) as varchar(20)) 
+ '/' +
CAST(datepart(day,StuffPriceTime) as varchar(20))
+ '/' +
CAST(datepart(year,StuffPriceTime ) as varchar(20))
+ ' ' +
CAST(datepart(hour,StuffPriceTime ) as varchar(20))
+ ':' +
CAST(datepart(minute,StuffPriceTime ) as varchar(20))
as datetime) as StuffPriceTime
```

If I use AVG(), it will average the StuffPrice amounts that happened inside of the minute. What I'm actually looking for the is the most recent StuffPrice for that one minute period. I think MAX() will pick the highest StuffPrice for the minute, not necessarily the most recent.

Saying it another way, if I had four rows like this:

```
 145, 10.02, 2014-12-31 09:21:15.000
 147, 10.89, 2014-12-31 09:21:24.000
 163, 10.71, 2014-12-31 09:21:38.000
 181, 10.54, 2014-12-31 09:21:59.000
```

I can group them all into the time period of 09:21:00, but I want the 10.54 value as it represents the most recent value for that period/grouping (the highest datetime value for the grouping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using window functions.  One way is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select cast(left(convert(varchar(255), StuffPriceTime, 120), 16) + ':00' as datetime),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then StuffPrice end) as FirstPrice,
       max(case when seqnum = cnt then StuffPrice end) as LastPrice
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(convert(varchar(255), StuffPriceTime, 120), 16)
                                order by StuffPriceTime) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by left(convert(varchar(255), StuffPriceTime, 120), 16)) as cnt
      from stuff s
     ) s
group by cast(left(convert(varchar(255), StuffPriceTime, 120), 16) + ':00' as datetime);
```

This also changes the date/time logic to use strings, because it is a big shorter.

Note:  you can also do this with `first_value()` and `last_value()`.  But, in SQL Server, these are only available as window functions, so you still need the subquery.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, where is "maxprice" coming from though (line 3) ?

Comment: @radpin . . . Another project I'm working on.  That should be `cnt`.

Comment: That worked perfectly for what I needed, thanks. I'm in business!